# how to write a select query in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with column named `place` which holds data like `1`,`2`,`3`(comma separated values). I need to get the details of the table where `place = 1`

```
select * from schools where place = 1
```

Comment: Thats a bad DB design you should normalize data and store place per schools in an association table.

Comment: actual count is 4 but i get only 3 list

Comment: column value is like 2,1,3 for 1st row 2nd row value may be 1, 3rd row value may be 1......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM schools WHERE FIND_IN_SET('1',place);
```

For more information about FIND_IN_SET refer this: [FIND_IN_SET](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
select * from schools where place LIKE '%1%'
```

Comment: it will return 21 related data also if place column will have 21.